# Firemonkey TCameraComponent settings restoring problem

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I've problem with TCameraComponent (Delphi Rio 10.3.1), similar to this one:
[Firemonkey TCameraComponent quality change when reactivated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830038/firemonkey-tcameracomponent-quality-change-when-reactivated)
but neither accepted answer nor comments suggestion work for me.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.CameraOn;
begin
  Camera := TCameraComponent.Create(Self);
  Camera.Quality := TVideoCaptureQuality.LowQuality;
  Camera.OnSampleBufferReady := CameraSampleBufferReady;
  Camera.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.CameraOff;
begin
  Camera.Active := False;
  Camera.OnSampleBufferReady := nil;
  //Self.RemoveComponent(Camera);
  //FreeAndNil(Camera);
  Camera.DisposeOf;
  Camera := nil;
end;
```

Setting quality to Low works only once. Then destroying and recreating TCameraComponent always restores quality settings to default (high). I'm quite aware of ARC issues with destroying objects, but none of methods I know work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. In `CameraOn` you create a camera and set the quality to low. Then, in `CameraOff` you destroy the camera. Next time you call `CameraOn` you create a new camera and set its quality to low. Do you mean that the quality will not be low after this action?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes, sounds ridiculous, but that's how it works.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation. I don't know what helps here, but have you tried changing quality *after* you activated the camera?

Comment: Yes I've tried, same result.